# How do you auto zoom/center Smart Map with multiple markers?

Tags: templating, plugins, plugin-smartmap

How can I auto center and zoom my [Smart Map](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/) with multiple markers?
Something like this:

```
var bounds = new smartMap.map.LatLngBounds();
smartMap.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 5):

So for starters, let's clear something up for anyone visiting this thread:

We're talking about **JavaScript**... specifically, how to manipulate a map that has **already been generated**. The official documentation on what kind of variables (maps/markers/info bubbles) which are created by the plugin [can be found here...](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/manipulating-the-map-in-javascript)

Beyond that, you can basically do anything you want with those JS variables. Much of that is beyond the scope of what I can help you with, but I'll try to at least point you in the right direction.

---

#### Map JS object

The way you'll want to refer to the map is like this:

```js
smartMap.map['smartmap-mapcanvas-1']
```

By default, the map will be called "smartmap-mapcanvas-1" (or 2, 3, etc). But this value can be easily overridden when creating your map, by [using the `id` parameter in your `options`](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/customizing-the-map-in-twig).

Now that you've got this map object, you can do anything you want via the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

#### Marker JS objects

When you're referring to **individual markers**, the format looks like this:

```js
smartMap.marker['smartmap-mapcanvas-1.100.myAddressField']
```

That naming scheme breaks into three separate components:

- Your map ID ("smartmap-mapcanvas-1")
- The element ID ("100")
- The field handle ("myAddressField")

Now that you've got this marker object, you can do anything you want via the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker).

#### Info bubble JS objects

The format for **marker info bubbles** is nearly identical:

```js
smartMap.infoWindow['smartmap-mapcanvas-1.100.myAddressField']
```

Now that you've got this info window object, you can do anything you want via the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow).

#### Debugging

Finally, since it's not always clear what maps, markers, and info bubbles have been created, you have these three functions available to you for debugging purposes...

- `smartMap.listMaps()`
- `smartMap.listMarkers()`
- `smartMap.listInfoWindows()`

---

Beyond that, you're really just asking a standard JavaScript and Google Maps API question. I'd highly recommend searching Stack Overflow (or just a Google search) to get the best results on "how to use fitBounds" or "how to zoom/center" a map.

Hope that helps!

Comment: *flag* - Not detailed enough answer.

Comment: Ha. I almost kept going, but I was afraid I would break Stack Exchange. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: You no longer need to apply `fitBounds` manually.**

As of [Smart Map 2.3.0](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-smartmap/blob/v3/CHANGELOG.md#230---2015-12-04), `fitBounds` will automatically be applied when rendering a map.