# How do I talk to Smart Map in JavaScript?

Tags: plugins, plugin-smartmap

Well, I know for a fact I am doing this incorrectly & it's going to be painfully obvious. I can see why (I think) but to be honest I just don’t “get it”.

I’m trying to style a Google map using Smart Map & JavaScript, but keep getting the JS error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: smartMap is not defined(…)
```

This is what my template looks like:

```
{# Google Map of location. #}
{% set options = {
    height: 500,
    width: '100%',
    zoom: 15,
    markerOptions: {
    },
    infoWindowOptions: {
        maxWidth: 200
    }
} %}

    <div id="mapCanvas">
        {{ craft.smartMap.map(product.address, options) }}
    </div>


    <script src="/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Within `app.min.js` I am doing this:

```
if ($('#mapCanvas').length) {
    var styles = [{
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}, {"hue": "#ff7700"}]
    },

    ...

    smartMap.map['smartmap-mapcanvas-1'].setOptions({styles: styles});
}
```

I've been reading [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/how-do-you-auto-zoom-center-smartmap-with-multiple-markers) which literally has the answer to my problem I believe. I just don't understand how to tell the system where/what `smartMap` is.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here is what the rendered page looks like:

```
<script src="/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.dev/cpresources/smartmap/js/smartmap.js?d=1449217510"></script>
```

**EDIT 2**

Just for future reference in case someone else comes across this thread. It ended up being the way I was initializing my js file.

```
// This executes before we're ready
(function () {
    'use strict';
    ...

})();


// This works
$(function () {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Are you seeing `smartmap/js/smartmap.js` get loaded? Is it loading before, or after `assets/js/app.min.js`?

Comment: Yep - it is after. I've updated my question to show what I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend loading your JS file **after** the `smartmap.js` file has been loaded. The `smartMap` JS object needs to exist before your code gets run.

Try loading your JS using the [includeJsFile](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/includejsfile) tag... I believe that should place it in the correct position.

```
{% includeJsFile "/assets/js/app.min.js" %}
```

If that doesn't work, then you may need to wrap your code in something that would prevent it from running until the page is fully loaded...

```js
$(function () {
    // Your code goes here
});
```

^ That example uses jQuery. The same can be achieved without jQuery, if you're not using it.

Comment: Interesting. I knew the problem was my stuff was rolling before smartMap was loading. Out of curiosity, is there a difference between loading the js via  twig like above or the "normal" way?

Comment: Nope, no difference at all.

Comment: Wrapping my styles in `$(function()...` fixed it for me. Thanks!